# Расшифровать данные sendmessageresult

Tags: шифрование

От сайта получил такой ответ. Как расшифровать данные? Заранее благодарен.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <SendMessageResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <SendMessageResult>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</SendMessageResult>
        </SendMessageResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: @simple87 Есть мнение, что это бинарные данные в [base64 кодировке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (изображение, медиа-данные)

Comment: @simple87, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Сделаю-ка я следующий шаг.

Вот такая простая программа:

```
var s = "UEsDBBQA...AAAAAA=="; // тут ваша строка
File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\decoded64.dat", Convert.FromBase64String(s));
```

создаёт бинарный файл на диске. Заглянув в него hex-редактором, видно, что он начинается с PK, что есть сигнатура упакованного файла. Переименуем файл в .zip (или откроем FAR'ом), и увидим, что файл является валидным Zip-архивом. Распаковав этот архив, получим другой бинарный файл, содержащий строки вида `VTS.DataModule, Version=1.0.5434.26160`. Также внутри видны куски rtf-текста наподобие

```
\fs36\'c2\'fb\'e4\'e5\'eb\'e5\'ed\'ed\'ee\'e5\lang1033  \lang1049\'f1\'eb\'ee\'e2\'ee\lang1033  \lang1049\'e2\lang1033  \lang1049\'ef\'f0\'e5\'e4\'eb\'ee\'e6\'e5\'ed\'e8\'e8\lang1033  \par
\ldblquote The capital of the United Kingdom lies on the \ul banks\ulnone  of the Thames.\rdblquote  \lang1049\'ff\'e2\'eb\'ff\'e5\'f2\'f1\'ff\cf0\fs24\par
```

Этот кусок легко понять, набив нужные байты в кодировке CP1251 (опять-таки, в HEX-редакторе или FAR'е):

```
Выделенное слово в предложении
«The capital of the United Kingdom lies on the _banks_ _none_ of the Thames.»
являетс
```

Также внутри очень много строк наподобие `_lastUserName`, `_name`, `_openedNamePC`, перед которыми лежит их длина. Всё это вместе похоже на бинарно сериализованные данные какого-то класса с полями, которые так называются.

Дерзайте!

---

Исходя из названий полей наподобие `_questionRTF`, `_answerYesNo`, `_timeInSec`, `_answer`, `_answerConformity`, `_distractor` `_disractorConformity` и т. п., полагаю, что мы имеем дело с описанием вопросов и ответов какой-то тестовой программы, общающейся со своим сервером.

---

Наличие имён полей типа `_ratingNeud`, `_ratingUd`, `_ratingHor` наталкивают на мысль, что мы имеем дело с отечественной разработкой.